# passing a different $model into renderPartial

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15 and am calling a view from 1 modules to another, and want to pass in the calculator model as $model so i can access the `attributeLabels()`

in my 1st modules view i have this code

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('application.modules.calculators.views.calculators._no_header-calculator', array('model'=>CalculatorsForm::model(), 'form'=>$form), false); ?>
```

and in `_no_header-calculator` i have this

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'yearloan'); ?>
```

problem is i'm getting this error, any idea why?

```
include(CalculatorsForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try including the model 1st then use `new CalculatorsForm`

```
<?php 

Yii::import('application.modules.calculators.models.CalculatorsForm');

$this->renderPartial('application.modules.calculators.views.calculators._no_header-calculator', array('model'=>new CalculatorsForm, 'form'=>$form), false); 

?>
```